# Template literals (Template strings) didn't give the exact result in arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am following a medium article about javascript es 6 template literals. But it didn't give me the result, but I type the exact code that showed in the article. I think maybe something silly that I had mistaken, but didn't able to find out.

```
const myFunctn=(name,age)=>{
return 'Hi ${name} , you are ${age} years old';
}
console.log(myFunctn('Said',22));
```

ok i think the output should have

```
Hi Said, you are 22 years old
```

But my output in the chrome browser console is below

```
Hi ${name} , you are ${age} years old
```

I had checked that ECMAScript is enabled in my browser, so that is not the issue. Maybe I had make some stupid mistakes.

Comment: use `\`backticks\`` not 'single quotes'

Comment: @George yes! that worked. I have told myself, it will be a silly one ..... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need backticks as delimiter for a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
const myFunctn = (name, age) => {
    return `Hi ${name} , you are ${age} years old`;
}

console.log(myFunctn('Said', 22));
```

Answer (score 1):

Template literals are not surrounded by quotes ('), but by backticks (`):

```js
const myFunctn=(name,age)=>{
return `Hi ${name} , you are ${age} years old`;
}
console.log(myFunctn('Said',22));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks ``.
In the case that your arrow function has a single expression as the function body, that expression will be executed, and the resulting value will be implicitly returned when the function is called.

```
 const myFunctn = (name, age) => `Hi ${name}, you are ${age} years old `;
```